# Trigonometry basic question

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am training Trigonometry just for fun, so I am not in a hurry, but would like to know how to answer this question - not the result, but how to do it. Sorry because I understand this is too basic for you, but I forgot almost everything from elementary school...

Question says:

> A sheet of paper measures $210  \space mm \times 297 \space mm$. Consider a diagonal from
>   one corner of the sheet to its opposite corner, and choose a point on
>   the diagonal so that its distance to the furthest edge of the sheet is
>   equal to the length of that edge, that is, $210 \space mm$. What is the
>   distance of the point to the nearest edge of the sheet?

This is the point I reached (did it in Paint - sorry about the quality): 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/UZhK9.png]

So as you can see I tried but with no success, and would like to know how to continue. Someone can help me?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: $x=\sqrt{297^2+210^2}-210$

Comment: Wouldn't "distance to the furthest edge" be from the point to one of the edges (not a corner)? So, the vertical line from $x$ to the bottom edge is 210mm. If this is the case, you want to use similar triangles.

Comment: To see what David meant, imagine a circle around your point and let the radius grow from 0 until the circle hit the boundary - that radius is the distance you search for.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't "distance to the furthest edge" be from the point to one of the edges (not a corner)? So, we can take the vertical line from your 'x" mark to the bottom edge to have length 210mm. If this is the case, you want to use similar triangles.

---

Warning: solution follows:

Draw a horizontal line from the point denoted by the "x" mark on your diagram to the right side of your rectangle and a vertical line from the point to the bottom side. This gives you two similar triangles: the "bottom" one, call it $B$, and the "top one", call it $T$.

Let $a$ be the length of the horizontal  side of $B$  and let $h$ be the height of the vertical side of $T$. Let $c$ be the length of the horizontal side of $T$ (see diagram below).

As remarked above, we set things up so that  the vertical side of $B$ has length $210$ and $h=87$.

A ratio of the non-hypotenuse sides of $B$ is 
${210\over a}$.

The corresponding ratio of the non-hypotenuse sides of $T$ is 
${87\over c}$.

The corresponding ratio of the non-hypotenuse sides of the lower triangle formed by the diagonal and the rectangle is ${297\over210}$.

Since the three triangles are similar
$$
{210\over a}={87\over c}={297\over 210}.
$$
From this, you can find the values of $a$ and $c$.  Then you can find the shortest distance to an edge.

---

Not to scale. 
[image: not to scale]